# VBA lookup refer to first sheet in workbook not "Sheet1"

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

How would I change the below lookup to refer to the first sheet in the workbook and not 'Sheet 1'?

```
.Range("I15:I" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
                       "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-8],[" & combinedWorkbook.Name & "]Sheet1!C1:C2,1,TRUE)=RC[-8],VLOOKUP(RC[-8],[" & combinedWorkbook.Name & "]Sheet1!C1:C2,2,TRUE),NA())"
```

Thanks

Comment: Do concatenating `combinedWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name` into the formula string instead of "Sheet1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are concatenating already the workbook name into the formula. The same way you could concatenating the name of the first worksheet too. The first worksheet is the first sheet in workbook's `Worksheets` collection.

So `combinedWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name` would be the name of the first worksheet in workbook `combinedWorkbook`.

But names could containing spaces like "My Worksheet Name". Then the reference itself must be within single quotes like `'My Worksheet Name'!A1`.

So all together:

```
.Range("I15:I" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
                       "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-8],'[" & combinedWorkbook.Name & "]" & combinedWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name & "'!C1:C2,1,TRUE)=RC[-8],VLOOKUP(RC[-8],'[" & combinedWorkbook.Name & "]" & combinedWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name & "'!C1:C2,2,TRUE),NA())"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to re-use it then I would declare:

```
Dim first_sheet As String
first_sheet = combinedWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name
```

And then use it in your code like this:

```
.Range("I15:I" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
                       "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-8],[" & combinedWorkbook.Name & "] & first_sheet & !C1:C2,1,TRUE)=RC[-8],VLOOKUP(RC[-8],[" & combinedWorkbook.Name & "] & first_sheet  & !C1:C2,2,TRUE),NA())"
```

Comment: `...,[" & combinedWorkbook.Name & "] & first_sheet & !C1:C2...` This concatenating syntax is wrong. Should be `...,'[" & combinedWorkbook.Name & "]" & first_sheet & "'!C1:C2...`.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I did not look at the rest of the code.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is really a small example how to refer to the first worksheet.

1. Take the name of the first worksheet and save it as a variable, using the `.Name` property.
2. Concatenate the variable in the formula:

---

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim wks1 As String
    wks1 = Worksheets(1).Name
    'worksheets should not contains spaces! :) left and right
    Worksheets(1).Name = Trim(wks1)
    Range("I15:I20").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & wks1 & "!R1C1"

End Sub
```

Comment: @AxelRichter - Thank you for the comment! If the worksheet contains spaces this is bad design. And I would love to have an error, which is showing me that. Still, updated :). Concerning the `combinedWorkbook`, the code is supposed to give a general example, not a specific one for the users.